# Taborder jumping between frames

Tags: vba, excel, event-handling

I have a userform containing 3 frames that all include several textboxes. I would like to be able to tab the textboxes across frames.

So, something like this: Frame1 - Textbox1 > Frame2 - Textbox1 > Frame3 - Textbox1 > Frame1 - Textbox2 > Frame1 - Textbox3 > Frame2- Textbox2

The textboxes are dynamically added and stored in an array according to the desired taborder, so the desired order is easily accesible. I just cant seem to find a way to apply this.

It would of course be possible to change the frame layout. However, the frames are used both to control the placement of the textboxes, and also to add separate scrollbars if the amount of textboxes exceeds the frame area.

Is something like this possible? Any help or suggestions much appreciated.

Edit: Added picture of the 3 frames
[Frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I44I.jpg)

Edit2:
I think destination-datas comment put me on the right track.

I created a class module

```
Public WithEvents TxtBox1 As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub TxtBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   MsgBox ("Test")
End Sub

Private Sub TxtBox1_change()
   MsgBox ("Test")
End Sub
```

And then in the sub that generates the textboxes, for the textboxes where I want to jump frames I do:

```
Dim tabArray1() As New TabBox1
Dim inputfelt As MSForms.TextBox

Set inputfelt = Hovedvindu.SkjemaFrame.SenderFrame.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "M" & i & "SenderNavn", True)
Set tabArray1(i).TxtBox1 = inputfelt
```

This adds all the correct textboxes to an array so that I can make an Exit event that changes focus, which I think should not be too diffucult.
However, I cant seem to get the events to fire properly.
The change event seems to work when I change the textboxes with a sub, for example when I tested that the correct textboxes are added to the array by looping through and changing the text of the textboxes in the array. But when I change the textboxes manually, nothing happens. The exit event doesnt seem to work at all.

Im not too experienced with event handling, so I might have missed something.

Comment: Please provide some sort of code so that we might be able to recreate your setup, or tell you where to include relevant line(s) of code.

Comment: Not directly.  Each frame has its own tab index, which prevents you from jumping back and forth between frames.  You could add an event handler to each text box to manually move the focus.  But that is hard to do with dynamically created controls (VBA does not support control arrays).  Frames are supposed to group related controls.  Jumping back and forth between groups suggests the controls within a group aren't related?

Comment: To elaborate on the grouping of controls I have edited in a picture of the 3 frames with textboxes. The text boxes are input data for the calculation of a measurement result, 2 lines belong to each measurement, as shown by the dashed lines. The numbers in the textboxes is the desired taborder. The frames are different parts of the input to each measurement which I want to separate visually This coould be done with an empty picture frame or similar. The trouble is that I want the scrollbars for each frame when the amount of textboxes exceed the frame area.

Comment: maybe you can add a "ghost" textbox.  .... several would be in a frame. ... example: frame1-textbox1 > frame1-ghost1 .... tabbing into a ghost would cause displayed frame change

Answer (score 0):

I found an acceptable solution. The approach described in Edit 2 of the original post worked once I moved the definition of the TabArray() outside the sub, so that  I keep track of the textboxes after the sub is ended.

I have one array, and one class module for the "end" textboxes on each of the 3 frames. The class modules tracks keydown on Tab. The 3 class modules are identical, except that they store the tabindex of the textbox from where the focus jumps to another frame in 3 different hidden labels on the userform. Keeping track of the tabindex allows me to know where to start when focus comes back to a frame.

the 3 class modules look like this:

```
Public WithEvents TxtBox1 As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub TxtBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal 
Shift As Integer)
   If KeyCode = vbKeyTab Then
      'store tabindex
      Hovedvindu.Controls("SisteTab1").Caption = 
      Hovedvindu.SkjemaFrame.SenderFrame.ActiveControl.TabIndex
      'call sub that moves the focus
      flyttfokus (1)
   End If
End Sub
```

The sub that moves focus is shown below. Input is just an integer (1,2 or 3) depending on which class module the call comes from, and thus which frame to move from/to. The sub reads the 3 hidden labels to know which textbox to start from when the focus is moved to a new frame. Error handling in the last case is for when the focus is moved from the very last textbox in the 3d frame. This will try to move focus to a non-existing textbox in the first frame, which will throw an error which can be ignored.

```
Sub flyttfokus(SisteFrame As Integer)
    Dim St1 As Integer
    Dim St2 As Integer
    Dim St3 As Integer
    St1 = CInt(Hovedvindu.Controls("SisteTab1").Caption)
    St2 = CInt(Hovedvindu.Controls("SisteTab2").Caption)
    St3 = CInt(Hovedvindu.Controls("SisteTab3").Caption)

    Select Case SisteFrame
        Case 1
            Hovedvindu.SkjemaFrame.MottakerFrame.Controls(St2 + 1).SetFocus
        Case 2
            Hovedvindu.SkjemaFrame.InfoFrame.Controls(St3 + 1).SetFocus
        Case 3
            On Error Resume Next
            Hovedvindu.SkjemaFrame.SenderFrame.Controls(St1 + 1).SetFocus
            On Error GoTo 0
    End Select

   End Sub
```

This solution will work as desired when starting from the very first textbox. If the user however, mouseclicks to a textbox for example on the second line and then starts tabing, focus will be moved back to the first line when focus is moved between frames. This is because the variables (labels) that keeps track og the Tabindex from where to start when a frame receives focus are only updated as the user tabs through the sheet. It is probably possible to update these variables on mousclick to a textbox, based on the amount of textboxes that are generated by the program. For my purposes this is not deemed necessary.